# intercept between straight line and circle

Tags: r, math

Imagine we have the circle defined by:

```
X^2 + Y^2 = r^2
```

The origin of the circle is `0` and `radius = 1`. If we draw a horizontal line from the origin moving to the right with coordinates `(x1,y1)=(0,0)` and `(x2,y2) = (2,0)` this line should intersect the circle.  e.g.

```
library(plotrix)
plot(0,0,xlim=c(-3,3),ylim=c(-2,2))
draw.circle(0,0,1)
lines(c(0,2),c(0,0))
```

[image]

I have tried to find the intersect of the line with the circle but with no luck.  I took 
my approach from the this [wolfram page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) and produce the following code but it does not seem to produce the correct result. Can someone please point me to my (no doubt) stupid mistake?

```
r <- 1
id <- 1:5
x1 <- c(0)
y1 <- c(0)
x2 <- c(2)
y2 <- c(0)
df <- data.frame(id,x1,y1,x2,y2)

df <- transform(df, dx = x2-x1)
df <- transform(df, dy = y2-y1)
df <- transform(df, dr = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2))
df <- transform(df, D  = (x1*y2)-(x2*y1))
df <- transform(df, dysign = sapply(dy,function(x) ifelse(x < 0,-1,1)))
df <- transform(df, newxplus = (D*dy + (dysign*dy) *dx*sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
df <- transform(df, newxneg  = (D*dy - (dysign*dy) *dx*sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
df <- transform(df, newyplus = (-D*dx + (abs(dy)) *sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
df <- transform(df, newyneg  = (-D*dx - (abs(dy)) *sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)

# where newxplus and newxneg are the two x coordinates for the two possible intercepts
# similarly for newyplus and newyneg
df
```

Comment: So, you want the intersection of a circle centred at the origin with radius `r` with a horizontal line from the origin?? Or an arbitrary circle centred anywhere with an arbitrary horizontal line?? And are you averse to an analytic (i.e. exact, calculated from a formula rather than numerically) solution or must it use R somehow (because this can be solved using maths and a calculator; there is no need for R in particular)? Please clarify.

Comment: an arbitrary circle and an arbitrary line. I centred the origin at zero for ease. I picked the horizontal line as an example as I could easily know the result I should expect so I can test my code/approach.

Comment: OK, and is there any reason you want it all to be in a data frame?

Comment: I am particularly excited by fast solutions in `r` that may improve on my approach even if the error i have lies in simple mathematics.

Comment: the dataframe approach allowed me to see the results of the steps as i went.  however in practice i will have a data frame of starting `x`s and `y`s and i will be generating new vectors in the `df` with intersect coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a typo in your calculation of `newxplus`, and `newxneg`.

The notation `sgn*(dy)` on the [wolfram page you linked](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) is the function `sgn*` *applied* to the value `dy`, i.e. your column `dysign`, *not* the column `dysign` *multiplied* by `dy`.

so:

```
# df <- transform(df, newxplus = (D*dy + (dysign*dy)*dx*sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
df <- transform(df, newxplus = (D*dy + dysign*dx*sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
# df <- transform(df, newxneg  = (D*dy - (dysign*dy)*dx*sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
df <- transform(df, newxneg  = (D*dy - dysign*dx*sqrt(r^2*dr^2-D^2))/dr^2)
```

Giving your x coordinates of the intercepts of -1 and +1.

Note that the page you linked is for the intersection of an *infinite* line with the circle which is why you got two intersections, but you can later apply the x/y limits of the lines to the output intersections to filter which ones you want if you are using *finite* lines.

Also you mention you're only using a dataframe for now in the practice (note that the 5 rows you have are always the same...), but when you write your full version of this function I recommend pre-calculating the value `sqrt(r^2 * dr^2 - D^2)` since it's used to calculate both the x and y coordinates.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I misunderstood the `sgn*(x)` expression!. And precalculating `sqrt(r^2 * dr^2 - D^2)` will definitely bring some more speed.